# How to get Logo in Action Bar on left side?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar saadaAB = getSupportActionBar();
        saadaAB.setLogo(R.drawable.run);
        saadaAB.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        saadaAB.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I want to print a logo in action bar in my app but this code make that logo in center and remove text in action bar.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it in 2 ways

**1. if Apptheme is in**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

You can just call

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.squarebox);// set drawable icon
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**2. or you can customize toolbar like**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Here goes your UI -->

</LinearLayout>
```

with java

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.custom_icon);
```

Comment: 1. In this case logo cover the whole action bar. I didn't get the answer.

Comment: 2. In this case app crash.

Comment: what does the stack say?